# csrfmiddlewaretoken error while creating form using cripsy-forms

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-crispy-forms, django-1.7

I am beginner in django (using django 1.7) and trying to create a form using crispy-forms in order to add new product to db. The problem is, form is working but it is not creating new product in database.

when I logged, if i click to save button nothing happen and shows below in address bar.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/add_product/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=kfGpEA6ZC32Lad9m9uwWZEhElwBGLHPA&csrfmiddlewaretoken=kfGpEA6ZC32Lad9m9uwWZEhElwBGLHPA&Category_IDCategory=66&DealType=Rent&Title=kkjkj&Price=78&Description=kjjk&save=Save
```

if I logged out and click to save button it directs me to the homepage as I provide in form but still no new product in database.

The problem looks like related to user and csrf, but still couldnt figure out the exact problem even I searched need your help.

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
 DealType_Choice = (
    ("Sale", "Sale"),
    ("Rent", "Rent"),
    ("Swap", "Swap"),
    ("Free", "Free"),
    ("Announ", "Announ"),

)
 DealType = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, choices=DealType_Choice)
 Title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
 Description = models.TextField(blank=False)
 Price = models.IntegerField(max_length=11, null=True)
 User_IDUser = models.ForeignKey(User)
 Category_IDCategory = models.ForeignKey(Category)
 PubDate = models.DateField("Publication Data")

 def __str__(self):
     return self.Title
```

views.py

```
def add_product(request):
   product_form= ProductForm(request.POST)
   if product_form.is_valid():
       form=product_form.save(commit=False)
       form.User_IDUser= request.user
       form.save()
       return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
   else:
       product_form= ProductForm()
   return render(request, 'add_productts.html', {'product_form':product_form})
```

forms.py

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
   Category_IDCategory=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), label="Category")
   DealType=forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=Product.DealType_Choice, label="DealType")
   Title=forms.CharField(label='Title', max_length=70)
   Price=forms.IntegerField(min_value=0, label='Price')
   Description=forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(), label="Description")

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.form_method = "POST"
    self.helper.form_action= "/"
    self.helper.layout= Layout(
        Field('Category_IDCategory',css_class='input-sm'),
        Field('DealType',css_class='input-sm'),
        Field('Title',css_class='input-sm'),
        Field(PrependedText('Price', 'TL', '.00'),css_class='input-sm'),
        Field('Description',css_class='input-sm', rows=5),
        FormActions(
            Submit('save', 'Save', css_class='btn btn-labeled btn-info'))
    )
    super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class Meta:
    model=Product
    fields= ['Category_IDCategory','DealType', 'Title','Price', 'Description']
```

template

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

    <h1>Add Product</h1>{% csrf_token %}
    {% crispy product_form %}


{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
...
url(r'^add_product/$', add_product),
...

)
```

Comment: Have you specified the CsrfMiddleware in settings.py as well?

Comment: settings.py has it as 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',

Comment: Could you show your urls.py?

Comment: @torm added to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is wrong:

```
self.helper.form_action= "/"
```

`form_action` should refer to add_product function:

```
self.helper.form_action= "/add_product/"
```

Comment: it directed to the http://127.0.0.1:8000/add_product/<url_to_add_product> and its not exist.

Comment: Did you change exactly to `self.helper.form_action= "/add_product/"` (with first `/`)?

Comment: many thanks! when i logged out, it said user cannot be NULL, i proved spesific user id as "form.User_IDUser_id= 3" and it worked!! but still not working when logged.

Comment: solved the logged in user issue. It turned out that there is an unclosed tag in index.html. hope helps for others who face same problem.